# Zealous Crop that will arrange elements independent of each other

Tags: gimp, crop

I'm trying to remove whitespace with a Zealous Crop.

In both Gimp and XnView MP they'll crop the whitespace and move elements closer together, but whitespace remains above and below each element relative to the other elements positioning in the image.

There are about 8 elements in the image of fairly equal spacing and they're all of similar size, is there a function I can use that'll essentially rearrange them so I get the least amount of whitespace around each element which will effectively arrange the elements in a horizontal row?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Align and Distribute tool <kbd>Q</kbd> in GIMP.

Each object needs to be on its own transparent layer, then do *Layer > Crop to content* on each layer to crop the layer to its content.

In the Tool Options for the Align and Distribute tool, you can use Relative to "Selection", "Distribute vertical centres of targets" to align them in a horizontal row, then "Distribute targets evenly in the horizontal", and enter an Offset X value to narrow the space between them.

Note: to select multiple targets hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click on them. Each target shows as four square handles when selected.

Example

[image]

Finally, you could remove the background layer if you have one, and do *Image > Crop to content*, then if you still need a white background add a new white filled background layer.